# Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt/: Permission denied

Tags: android

I am novice android developer & i am learning  android from this book http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=9780321673350

I am on  chapter 10.

Everything is working fine but when i click on "settings" tab than the following error flashes -  Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt/: Permission denied

& after this all i see is a blank screen.

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: This is not the actual error in your program.  Rather it is a problem in the error reporting code, which you can ignore for now.  When you fix the actual problem causing your program to crash, you will stop triggering the code which tries to write to this file.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure adb is in you system path or cd to it first.
Then try the following:

```
adb shell
cd \data
chmod 777 anr
```

Then try again.
Don't ask me why the permissions go wonky, but I've had this too.

Answer (score 2):

Try getting rid of the trailing slash; this is a file, not a directory.

Comment: The trailing slash is almost surely a transcription mistake in creating the post here. The message itself is widely reported, usually with a correct filename. By all appearances it is a configuration problem in past versions of Android - in recent releases /data/anr/traces.txt seems to be world writable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by passing the correct context to the Traces class method call.